# How should I refinish a pine shelf unit?

Tags: shelving

I'm refinishing a shelf unit made out of pine and painted. It has a lot of holes and cuts in it (I think it was used as a cutting table, or was near one). It's solid, so I want to refinish it and paint it again. I want to patch the holes, nicks and dents. Should I use wood filler spackle stuff or plaster/mud to patch the holes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plaster/mud is not meant for wood, it's meant for plaster/drywall, so you definitely should use wood filler.